# error in running react native on emulator

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, build.gradle

trying to run a react native project and i have downloaded all the SDK,NDK,platform tools needed for this project and im getting this error:

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0.

here is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '33.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '21')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        if (findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')) {
            kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')
        }
        frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried **build/ clean project** + **build/ rebuild project** + **file/ Invalidate caches / restart** ?